# "No package found" error when installing NGINX on CentOS 5

Tags: nginx, centos

The command `sudo yum install nginx` returns the error `No package nginx available`. I've tried this before and it worked but now it doesn't.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx isn't in the 'normal' Centos [repositories](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).  You can install the [EPEL](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x) repository to gain access to it.  There's a how to guide [here](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/12/17/centos-installing-nginx-via-yum) - and a more up to date one [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/enable-epel-repository/).

Once you have added the EPEL repo, you can then install with the yum command you referenced.